# why selection does not work as it should? angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

HTML---->

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="seleccione">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Seleccione</mat-header-cell>

<!--<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
<mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
[checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
[indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
</mat-checkbox>
</mat-header-cell>-->

<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<mat-checkbox #checkbox="matCheckbox"
(change)="$event ? masterToggle(row) : null"
                    >

</mat-checkbox>
</mat-cell>

</ng-container>
```

COMPONENT.TS---->

```
masterToggle(row) {

console.log("row---->", row);
console.log("this.selection.selected---->", this.selection.selected);
console.log("this.selection.selected.length---->", this.selection.selected.length);
console.log("selection.isSelected---->", this.selection.select(row));

}
```

The problem is that when I click once on the checkbox then the value of "selected" and "lenght" returns empty but when I double-click it returns as it should.

Could someone tell me that I am not considering?

Comment: I've seen this problem before, typically I attempt to change z-order to make the clickable part at top of hierarchy.

Comment: @JohnPeters There must be a solution, there are many stackblitz with checkbox that work perfectly but in my case I don't see what I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox="matCheckbox"
(change)="$event ? masterToggle(row) : null"
 z-order:20
>
```

I think the reason double click works is that the first click changes focus that is now within the scope of the checkbox.  It's like there's a layer above the checkbox.